# Itihasa and Dharmashastra, Nitishastra and Dharmasutra

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, dharma-shastras, nitishastra, dharmasutra

What were the rules used by the famous kingdoms during the events of Ramayana and Mahabharata? If none is provided would it be fair to assume that the Dharmasutras were the sacred law? Also if not separate Dharmashastra is mentioned is there a section of these famous works that outlines such ethics and morals?

Comment: All dharmashastras (manu, yajnavalkya, etc) come under vedanga. In ramayana it is clearly mentioned that rama was an expert in veda and vedanga

Comment: @ekAntika cool, but like which ones should I read for the best summary of rules used during those times?